# htaccess Block all the request if request does not contains specific string patterns

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Laravel web site with the localization, for that web site I need to allow the requests with the URL patterns mentioned below.
If not match with this URL pattern, need to navigate to the 404 page.

```
https://www.sampledomain.ch/
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/de
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/it
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/fr
https://www.sampledomain.ch/de
https://www.sampledomain.ch/it
https://www.sampledomain.ch/fr
```

Can anyone guide me to do this by htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1.) With .htaccess

#### Code with comments

```
# Run this code IF "mod_rewrite" module was enabled
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Enable server-side redirects
    RewriteEngine On

    # If the part after the domain is existed (so not just domain)
    #
    # %{REQUEST_URI}: the part after the domain
    # !^/*$: not empty after "/"
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*$
    # AND
    # If the part after the domain not end with de, it, or fr
    #
    # %{REQUEST_URI}: the part after the domain
    # !: not
    # /(de|it|fr): /de or /it or /fr
    # $: need end of url after (de or it or fr)
    # [NC]: treats lowercase and uppercase letters equally
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(de|it|fr)$ [NC]
    # In that case, it returns a 404 error
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(de|it|fr)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Test Cases

```
https://www.sampledomain.ch/ # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/de # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/it # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/fr # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/some_text/de # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/some_text/it # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/some_text/fr # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/de # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/it # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/fr # OK (not redirected)

https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/DE # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/It # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/some_text/rF # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/De # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/iT # OK (not redirected)
https://www.sampledomain.ch/FR # OK (not redirected)

https://www.sampledomain.ch/FR123 # 404 error
https://www.sampledomain.ch/fr/test # 404 error
https://www.sampledomain.ch/a # 404 error

etc.
```

## 2.) Using Laravel Route (better option)

However, if you are using Laravel, it is worth reconsidering the use of the built-in router as well!

The example, however, requires that we move the language code to the beginning of the URL, which is generally a common practice.

`1. domain` `2. language` `3. any other parameters`

```php
Route::get('/{language}/{any}', function ($language, $any) {
    // Handle the request in this function.
    // The $language variable contains the language value,
    // and the $any variable contains any part of the URL.
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Your task now is to handle the allowed languages.

```php
Route::get('/{language}/{any}', function ($language, $any) {
    $allowedLanguages = ['de', 'en', 'fr'];

    if (!in_array(Str::lower($language), $allowedLanguages)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    // If the language is valid, we can continue with the processing.
})->where('any', '.*');
```

More information here: [Laravel Documentation - Route Parameters Encoded Forward Slashes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes)

Comment: I have try this, when I enter https://www.sampledomain.ch, its redirected to 404 page.

Comment: Indeed. I have corrected it. The mentioned faulty URL address has also been tested!

Comment: I have added a solution with Laravel as well! I think the result will be much more customizable and functional if we don't want to solve the task with htaccess!

Comment: I have try with new update and it's now working, but it prevent loading images, js and css files. So I have add below code 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp4$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpeg$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ttf$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.svg$ [NC]

after that I was able to load that files, but some webp images are still not loading.

Comment: Need to add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.webp$ [NC] --- I really didn't think of those. Although I note that the problem would not have existed with the Laravel solution!